# tf for every child frame?

Tags: ros, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,
Is there any possibility to kind of "get" all child frames of a specific frame?
I want to make a transformation (simple rotation on 2 axis) to every child frame of a specific frame. Something like a list which i can iterate through would be awesome, but I'm open to other ideas for sure.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261460/tf-for-every-child-frame?/) by [Flacedoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30330/flacedoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not an API to support that query specifically.

There is a method to [get all the frames as yaml](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1BufferCore.html#af731e42ed6368295d945345592a2c77a) which you can then iterate and filter based on the parent.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0